# Is there a way to run more than one jarfile using -cp or -jar as just ONE command?

Tags: java, jar

Is there a way to run basically: `java -jar file1.jar, file2.jar` (Using only that one command, not using it twice in a row?)

Or using `java -cp file1.jar file2.jar` (Again, using the command only ONCE to run TWO .jar files?)

(Using Cmd Prompt/Terminal/etc)

If so, how?

Comment: Note: Is there a way to do this without adding anything before the "java" section of the command*

Comment: I'll give a specific example:
Folder1: JavaServer1.jar ||
Folder2: JavaServer2.jar ||

Is there a way to have each jar generate/read it's own files in it's own folder AND run them both with one command?

Comment: I did'nt understand ur example! folder1 has 1st jar and folder2 has 2nd jar and u want to run both the jar files at a time (or) one after the other. is that it?

Comment: Well, basically, I'd like to run them both with one command. Both running at the same time (not necessarily starting at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

```
java -classpath <your path>\file1.jar -jar  file2.jar
```

Idea is provide one jar as primary jar and everything else can go to class path.

Comment: That doesn't run both of the jars. Just now tried it

Answer (score 0):

You can use nohup for this:-

```
nohup java -jar file1.jar & && nohup java -jar file2.jar &
```

Explanation:-

```
     * nohup is used to run the bash commands back ground(Ex:- nohup ls &).

     * && is used to combine two bash commands into a single command but run both 
        the commands

     * Here I am trying to combine and run two background processes.
```

You can see these processes running using the bash command "top" and checking appropriate process no.

Hope this helps!

If you want the processes not to run in background and if you want to see the output live use this bash Command!

```
java -jar file1.jar & java -jar file2.jar &
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Is there a way to do that w/out nohup? Without adding anything before "java"

Comment: @S0N_0F_A_S0N is it ok for u to run the jar files one after the other then use this "java -jar file1.jar && java -jar file2.jar"

Comment: That didn't work. :/ It only ran the first .jar file, not the other.

Comment: @S0N_0F_A_S0N Ya Most probably the problem will be this. They might be in different directories. "java -jar /path/to/first/jar/jarfile/file1.jar && java -jar /path/to/second/jar/file2.jar "

Comment: @S0N_0F_A_S0N It is a well checked solution. It is working for me!

Comment: I did that and it ran the first jar, but not the second at the same time. The second jar only ran after the first jar quit/closed.

Comment: @S0N_0F_A_S0N Can you try the updated code and tell me whether it works or not?